# How to efficiently sort hundreds thousands of data input in C++?

Tags: c++, data-processing

Suppose I have 10000+ of Epoch Timestamps spanning a month long that need to be sorted.

In the program, I have to sort these Epoch Timestamps (consist with 13 digits `long long int`, like `1359997200000` means Feb 4, 2013 5:00PM) into 16 different days between the hour of 8AM to 5PM, in a interval of 10, 120, and 300 seconds.

Each epoch timestamps can be converted to real time using `ctime`

That is, if a epoch timestamps is `1359964803000` ( February 4, 2013 8:00:03) it will be grouped into the interval of `1359964800000`(February 4, 2013 8:00:00) and `1359964809000` (February 4, 2013 8:00:09)

It there a efficient way to do this in C++ without manually defining thousands of arrays? I know such application could be better off to data processing language like Matlab or R but I want to see some different solution.

Comment: "It there a efficient way to do this in C++ without manually defining thousands of arrays?" - Arrays of arrays? Not sure why you think you need to manually define thousands of arrays.

Comment: @BessieTheCow even with 2D arrays that still seems a lot.

Comment: Can you post an example of the file format?

Comment: Don't use any arrays. `vector`s will do the job.

Comment: @BessieTheCow basically I am trying to find out which data structure in C++ can best cope with this situation

Comment: That depends on the context.

Comment: The question appears to be completely unclear and confusing. First it poses the question as how to extract a small subset of data from a large file, then segways into a discussion about some unclear timestamps of some kind, without providing any kind of background material, or any kind of a logical connection to the initial description. You should 
try to pretend that you don't know anything beforehand, wipe your mind clear of all existing knowledge, that start reading this question, see if you can actually understand it; then keep [edit]ing with your 1st mind until your 2nd mind groks it.

Comment: @BessieTheCow file sample added.

Comment: I'm not clear enough on what you propose to do to see why thousands of arrays would be an option under consideration.

Comment: Start at the bottom: Do you know how to read the files and extract the one column of interest?

Comment: @user4581301 yes

Comment: You could for example have a struct that stores the data in one row, and then you read the data into an array/vector of those structs. Then you iterate over the array and do whatever you want. It's still unclear what your problem is. What part are you stuck on?

Comment: @BessieTheCow question updated.

Comment: @BessieTheCow sorting. I managed to extract all the timestamps I need but I need to find a way to sort it efficiently.

Comment: What do you need to do with the data after it's been grouped by time interval? If you need to access the data in a specific time interval, you can store the data for each time interval in a vector and then store all those vectors in another vector. In other words, a vector of vectors containing the data for each interval.

Comment: Oh... for your "thousands of arrays", you  were thinking of defining one array for `February 4, 2013 8:00:00 through 8:00:09`, another for `February 4, 2013 8:00:10 through 8:00:19`, and so on (a total of 51,840 arrays)? *(Often it is helpful to explain the rationale for your proposed data structure, rather than assuming everyone else will get it right away. That's especially true when you've already deduced that your proposed structure is not a reasonable approach.)*

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you could do it with a single `std::vector` that you sort after reading the timestamps into it.  Once it is sorted, you can iterate over the vector once (well, once for each size of groups you want to define) to determine where within the vector each group starts:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

unsigned int CalculateSecondsSinceMidnightOnFirstDay(int whichDay, int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
{
   unsigned int ret = seconds;
   ret += (minutes*60);
   ret += (hours*60*60);
   ret += (whichDay*24*60*60);
   return ret;
}

unsigned int CalculateGroupIDFromSeconds(unsigned int secondsSinceMidnightOnFirstDay, unsigned int secondsPerGroup)
{
   return (secondsSinceMidnightOnFirstDay/secondsPerGroup);
}

int main(int, char **)
{
   std::vector<unsigned int> rows;

   // parse out the .csv files and add the timestamps
   // into (rows) here; for this example, I'll just fake it
   rows.push_back(CalculateSecondsSinceMidnightOnFirstDay(3,  6,  2, 15));
   rows.push_back(CalculateSecondsSinceMidnightOnFirstDay(0, 18, 35, 59));
   rows.push_back(CalculateSecondsSinceMidnightOnFirstDay(2,  8, 12, 17));
   rows.push_back(CalculateSecondsSinceMidnightOnFirstDay(2,  8, 12, 18));
   rows.push_back(CalculateSecondsSinceMidnightOnFirstDay(2,  8, 12, 19));
   // ... and so on

   // Now sort the data so that all timestamps are listed in increasing order
   std::sort(rows.begin(), rows.end());

   // Now that the vector is sorted, we can calculate the offset of each group within it
   const unsigned int groupSizeInSeconds = 10;

   unsigned int prevGroupID = (unsigned int) -1;
   for (size_t i=0; i<rows.size(); i++)
   {
      unsigned int curGroupID = CalculateGroupIDFromSeconds(rows[i], groupSizeInSeconds);
      if (curGroupID != prevGroupID)
      {
         printf("Group #%u starts at index #%lu in the array\n", curGroupID, i);
         prevGroupID = curGroupID;
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

If it turns out that you need to track other data from each CSV row in addition to the timestamp value, you could replace `std::vector<unsigned int>` with `std::vector<MyDataRecordClass>`, where `MyDataRecordClass` is a `class` or `struct` that you define that contains member-variables for both the timestamp-value and whatever other information you need to keep together with that value; in that case you'd also need to implement the `operator < (const MyDataRecordClass &> const` method of `MyDataRecordClass` to `return (this->_secondsSinceMidnightOnFirstDay < rhs._secondsSinceMidnightOnFirstDay);`, so that `std::sort()` would know how to correctly sort the vector into timestamp-ascending order.

Comment: I think it can be grouped, sorted and saved in epoch timestamp format then when in need, just pull it out and convert into real time format?

Comment: Yes; presumably you will have a function that converts an epoch-time/long-integer into a human-readable-string, and a second function that converts a human-readable-string into an epoch-time/long-integer.  Once you have those working, you can convert back and forth as necessary.